# ASP.NET cannot cast session variable in same type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, casting

i'm having some "almost random" error while trying to cast a session variable to it's belonging variable type.
Just to make it clear:

i have a class "Elemento", i just create an istance of it and place it in my session variable:

```
Elemento elem = new Elemento(id, quantity);
list.Add(elem);
context.Session["cart"] = list;
```

Now i have to recover my list, and i try to do it with:

```
list = (List<Elemento>)context.Session["cart"];
```

Well.. this "sometime" works, sometime not! The first time i tried it it worked flawlessy, but now i have "internal server error 500" with this error:

> Impossibile eseguire il cast di
>   [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Elemento] a
>   [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Elemento]. Il tipo A ha origine
>   da 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' nel contesto 'LoadNeither' nella
>   posizione
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Il tipo B ha origine da 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' nel contesto 'LoadNeither' nella
>   posizione
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

translating it..

> Cannot cast [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Elemento] to
>   [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Elemento]. Type A have origin
>   from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' with context 'LoadNeither' and
>   position
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Type B have origin from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' with context 'LoadNeither' and
>   position
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

i can solve this "for some time" emptying the IIS cache.. but it will happen again when i build the solution from visual studio.

i read in some place i can solve this using interfaces.. but since i'm still learning how to use them i can't try directly for now, there is some tested solution to this?

EDIT:
Works with krshekhar solution:

```
list = context.Session["cart"] as List<Elemento>;
```

thank you!

Comment: check whether your session context.Session["cart"] is exist and it is not null before casting.

Comment: yeah i already do that, sorry for not having wrote it in main post!

Comment: try using list = context.Session["cart"] as List<Elemento>;

Comment: woha! Seems like this is working! On the first run i got an error on the next istruction but restarting IIS all seems to work well! I hope this is stable eheh, thank you!

Comment: You say it works until you rebuild. Does it break every time it's rebuilt, or only when there are changes to the `Elemento` class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be a problem with IIS memory. Did you try to restart IIS? Using another IIS server?

I'd advise to use some other means to store objects - such as Cookies.

If you think about scalability - Cookies will provide you a better solution then session object, because they are stored at the client and not the server.

Best of luck

Comment: i can't use cookies for this :( restarting IIS works.. until i build again the project! whaaattt

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you get errors upon rebuilding, it seems the likelihood here is that there are changes to the fields within the `Elemento` class or another class that it references, which is breaking the deserialization of the object from the session state.

When storing "complex" objects into the IIS session state, they are serialized using `BinaryFormatter` (in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` namespace). This formatter is sensitive to changes in the classes being serialized, and may not successfully deserialize an object graph if any of the classes in the graph have change since the data was originally serialised. This seems to be the problem here given you say it breaks after rebuilding.

I would suggest that you either save only types from the BCL into the session state (since these will only change between .NET versions). Or better still, implement your own custom serialization by implementing the `ISerializable` interface on your `Elemento` object, which will allow you to maintain compatibility between builds of your project.

Comment: with krshekhar's solution all works well, i hope i must not reimplement an ISerializable interface eheh
but.. even with this solution sometime i get some corrupt data from session.. it's not related on when i build it, or the time passed, or the browser used.. still can't understand why